# Considering a curve $\alpha$ connecting the points $1$ and $-1$ in which is found above the axis X, Be the function $f(z)= z^i:=e^{i ln z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-integral-formula

could you help me with this question? I am a beginner and I struggling with it

Consider a curve $\alpha$ connecting the points $1$ and $-1$ in which is found above the axis X, except in the extreme. Be the function

$f(z)= z^i:=e^{i ln z}$

where $lnz$ is the main log of z

a. Calculate $\int _{\alpha} f(z)dz  $, assuming that $\alpha$ is the circuference $\alpha (t) =e^{it}$, $t$ $belongs$ $[-\pi, \pi]$

the answer given is $(\frac{-1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}i)(e^{-\pi} +1)$

b. Why is there not the antiderivative of $f$ in {$ z: -\pi  < arg z\leq \pi   $}

c. Verify that if $g(z)=e^{iLn(z)}$ , where $Ln (z)$ is the branch of the log defined in {$ \frac{-\pi}{2} < arg z\leq \frac{3\pi}{2}  $} so $g$ and $f$ coincide and $\alpha$

d. Find the primitive of g

the answer given is $ \frac{z^{i+1}}{i+1}$

e. Use (c) and (d) to computer $\int _{  \alpha} z^i:  $

the answer given is $ \frac{1+e^{-\pi}}{2} (1-i) $

Answer (score 1):

For the first, I did substitute $\alpha(t)=e^{it}$ so
\begin{align}
\int_\alpha z^i\,\mathrm{dz}
&= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{iit}ie^{it}\,\mathrm{dz} \\
&= i\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{t(i-1)}\,\mathrm{dz} \\
&= \dfrac{i}{i-1}\left[e^{\pi(i-1)}-e^{-\pi(i-1)}\right] \hspace{1cm};\hspace{1cm}e^{\pi}=e^{-\pi}=-1\\
&= \dfrac{1-i}{2}\left[e^{\pi}-e^{-\pi}\right] \\
&= (1-i)\sinh\pi
\end{align}
but it seems different from yours!